# Check window visibility with wmctrl

Tags: window, x11, visible

I want to check if a certain window is visible or not under X11. Imagine the case where there are several open windows on the deskop (= visible windows). Then show the desktop. I expect some value to change from "visible = 1" to "visible = 0" or something like that... Is there a way to get that information?

wmctrl -m does not work, as it always shows that the "show desktop mode" is ON, while being not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if the window manager, it work for me using the KDE window manager (kwm).

The `wmctrl` man page says:

```
-k  ( on  |  off  )
              Turn on or off the window manager's "show the desktop" mode (if the window manager  imple‐
              ments this feature).
```

I did `wmctrl -m` in a command window which showed the mode as `OFF` then `sleep 10; wmctrl -m` and selected the "Show the Desktop" icon.

When I reopened the command window, the mode was "ON".

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
After the first click on "show desktop", for me it was "ON", too. What is it, if you click a second time? For me, it is still "ON", but should be "OFF". Can you reproduce this?